# DB Comparer Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the `SQL server 2017` standard version. At the same, I am using `db comparer` for comparing databases..

When I click on the database name in `db comparer` tool,

> we got an error Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: That's the problem with free tools that were written to support obsolete versions of sql server - they stop working eventually. You need to contact the organization that wrote it or the one that supports it. Or find one that works with your current version of sql server.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1

Upgrade your SqlServer management studio from 2008 to 2012
Or Download the service packs of SqlServer Management Studio and update probably resolve you solution

You can download the SQL Server Management studio 2012 from below link
Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

---

solution 2

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

Install SSMS2014. Do it by click download on Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Express, then scroll down to the bottom and install SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. Then suddenly DBComparer started working again.